# Link attribute value to Fanout in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I would like to use attribute value from Workbench as an attribute that says Yes or No to the Fanout options in Workbench settings. So apply value from WB to the advanced fanout settings of WB.

Any idea?

Someone, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to prompt directly for a fanout Yes/No at run time.

I think the only way to do this would be to have two writers. One has a fanout set, the other doesn't. Then use a Tester to check the Yes/No status and direct features accordingly.

Otherwise, prompt the user what to fanout by, using "No Fanout" as an option that really means "fanout by exactly the same value each time" = all in the same file.